# Ocaml link error objective-c (cocoa)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, ocaml

I'm trying to call some objective-c code from within ocaml.

stubs.m

```
#include <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

#define CAML_NAME_SPACE

#include <caml/mlvalues.h>
#include <caml/memory.h>
#include <caml/callback.h>
#include <caml/alloc.h>
#include <caml/fail.h>

CAMLprim value ml_NSLog (value str)
{
  CAMLparam1 (str);
  NSLog (@"%s", String_val (str));
  CAMLreturn (Val_unit);
}
```

It gets compiled with the following command to `stubs.o`:

```
cc -Wextra -Wall -Werror -O -g -std=c99 -pedantic-errors -Wsign-compare -Wshadow -I /Users/Iwan/.opam/4.02.3/lib/ocaml   -c -o stubs.o stubs.m
```

My ocaml code in `index.ml` is:

```
external _NSLog: string -> unit = "ml_NSLog"

let log s = _NSLog s

let () = log "hello"
```

When I execute `ocamlopt -o app index.ml stubs.o` I get:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_NSLog", referenced from:
      _ml_NSLog in stubs.o
     (maybe you meant: _ml_NSLog)
  "___CFConstantStringClassReference", referenced from:
      CFString in stubs.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
File "caml_startup", line 1:
Error: Error during linking
```

Why do I get the error in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was brutally simple:

```
ocamlopt -cclib "-framework Cocoa" -o app index.ml stubs.o
```

I had to pas `"-framework Cocoa"` as option to the c linker...